# Why does Java8 Stream generate nothing?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;


public class TestPQ {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Comparator<String> comparator = new StringLengthComparator();
        PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>(10, comparator);
        queue.offer("Short");
        queue.offer("ABCahahahha");
        queue.offer("lululu");
        queue.stream().map( s-> {
            System.out.println("queue: "+ s);
            return s;
        });
    }
}
```

I have this code and I expect that I would see "Short", "lululu" and "ABCahahahha" been printed out.
But I don't see them. what's wrong with my code?
Compile is fine. and I am using java 8 compiler and runtime.

Comment: Keep in mind that `queue.stream()` will **NOT** produce the `PriorityQueue` content in sorted order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *map()* method itself is *intermediate* and does not enforce the consumption of a `Stream` so it's a very bad idea to put side effects there.

In this case, you should use the dedicated *forEach()* method:

```
queue.stream()
  .forEach(s -> System.out.println("queue: " + s));
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't have any terminal operation consuming your stream. So nothing happens. `map()` is an intermediate operation, which is not supposed to have side effects. What your code should be is

```
queue.stream().forEach(s-> {
    System.out.println("queue: "+ s);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

non terminal operation is not doing any processing. Its the terminal operation only, who start the processing of all the non terminal operation and then finally terminal operation.